# Bitnami Redmine showing error after upgrade from 2.4.2-0 to 2.6.0-0

Tags: redmine

We have upgraded the Bitnami Redmine from 2.4.2-0 to 2.6.0-0 on a Windows server.

When we try to access (localhost/redmine) but after upgrading Redmine, it shows the following error:

> Internal error
>
> An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
>   If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.
>   If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Below is the error found in log file,

```
GET "/redmine/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 14:19:53 +0530
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML Current user: anonymous Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65.0ms 
NoMethodError (undefined method passwd_changed_on' for #<AnonymousUser:0x67c50d8>): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:149:in force_logout_if_password_changed'
```

Comment: And when you checked your log files for errors as indicated in the message, what have you found?

Comment: @HolgerJust, Thanks for replying my comment. I have pasted the production logs of redmine below: 
Started GET "/redmine/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 14:19:53 +0530 Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML Current user: anonymous Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 65.0ms NoMethodError (undefined method passwd_changed_on' for #<AnonymousUser:0x67c50d8>): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:149:in force_logout_if_password_changed'

Answer (score 1):

You should run this command:

`% ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

In the root directory of your redmine install.